# Haskell: Find a value in a Ternary Tree and the tree is not sorted

Tags: haskell, tree, ternary-tree

For now I have the tree data type:

```
data TernaryTree a = EmptyTree
                   | Node a (TernaryTree a) (TernaryTree a) (TernaryTree a)
                   deriving (Show)
```

And I am trying to create a function that can loop up a value in the Ternary Tree.
The tree is not sorted.

```
treeLook :: (Ord a)=> a -> TernaryTree a -> Bool
treeLook x EmptyTree = False
treeLook x (Node a left mid right) =
    if x /= a
        then do
        treeLook x left 
        treeLook x mid
        treeLook x right
        else 
        True
```

I have this for now but I can't compile it. It says:

```
Couldn't match expected type "m0 b0" with actual type "bool" on the line:
    treeLook x right
```

Comment: Why do you use `do` here?

Answer (score 5):

`do` is a keyword that is used to enable some syntactical sugar for *monads*. In this sitation, there is no need for monads.

There are two cases here: the `EmptyTree` that means that we failed to find the value, so we return `False`.

For the `Node` we can check up to four conditions: is the value the value we look for, is the value in the first subtree, is the value in the second subtree, and is the value in the third subtree. From the moment one of the checks is `True`, we can return `True`. If all checks fail, we return `False`, this is the behavior of a logical or (`||`). So we can write it like:

```
treeLook :: Eq a => a -> TernaryTree a -> Bool
treeLook _ EmptyTree = False
treeLook x (Node a l m r) = x == a || treeLook x l || treeLook x m || treeLook x r
```

Or we can define a locally scoped function preventing us from recursively passing the value we are looking for:

```
treeLook :: Eq a => a -> TernaryTree a -> Bool
treeLook x = go
    where go EmptyTree = False
          go (Node a l m r) = x == a || go l || go m || go r
```

Note that since the tree is not sorted, we do not need the `Ord a` type constraint, we only need to check equality (here in `x == a`), so the `Eq a` type constraint is sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

Do is for monads.

Instead use [any](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=any).

```
treeLook _ EmptyTree = False
treeLook x (Node y l m r) = any id [x == y, look l, look m, look r]
    where look = treeLook x
```

As pointed out, or is better use.

```
treeLook x (Node y l m r) = or [x == y, look l, look m, look r]
    where look = treeLook x
```

Tho my favourite would be this:

```
treeLook _ EmptyTree = False
treeLook x (Node y l m r) = x == y || any (treeLook x) [l, m, r]
```

Comment: FTR, it is not completely absurd to see `do` in a situation similar to this, because it can also be used in the _list monad_. For this particular function, that doesn't seem to make any sense though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think the `Maybe` monad is much more the sort of thing one might expect in this context than the `[]` one

Comment: @DanRobertson not really, `Maybe` has AND-ish semantics but this is an OR-like situation. It could be done with the `Left` side of `Either`, but that's a bit weird.

Comment: @leftaroundabout you’re right of course. That totally slipped my mind. I suppose I was thinking of the `Alternative` instance which does have disjunction semantics but doesn’t necessarily use `do` notation.

Comment: `any` looks wrong here: the above code does not type check. You probably mean `or` instead of `any`.

Comment: @chi you are right, I didn't have haskell compiler at hand to test it at that moment.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `elem`, which checks whether a value is an element of a `Foldable` container.

```
treeLook :: Eq a => a -> TernaryTree a -> Bool
treeLook = elem
```

Now you just have to write an instance of `Foldable`. One option is to enable the `DeriveFoldable` extension and just use `deriving (Show, Foldable)` to get GHC to write the instance for you. But you won't learn much that way. So let's explore some ways to do it.

```
-- This import is needed for non-bleeding-edge GHC versions.
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

instance Foldable TernaryTree where
  -- Fold over the tree in pre-order
  foldMap _ EmptyTree = mempty
  foldMap f (Node x ls cs rs) =
    f x <> foldMap f ls <> foldMap f cs <> foldMap f rs
```

But that repeated `foldMap` is itself a sort of "pattern" you can pull out by writing the "catamorphism" for trees:

```
cataTree :: r -> (a -> r -> r -> r -> r) -> TernaryTree a -> r
cataTree e _ EmptyTree = e
cataTree e f (Node x ls cs rs) =
  f x (cataTree e f ls) (cataTree e f cs) (cataTree e f rs)
```

Now you can define `foldMap` thus:

```
foldMap f = cataTree mempty (\a lr cr rr -> f a <> lr <> cr <> rr)
```

Now `foldMap` itself has a more-powerful cousin, `traverse`. So another option is to start there:

```
import Data.Traversable (fmapDefault, foldMapDefault)

instance Traversable TernaryTree where
  -- Traverse the tree in pre-order
  traverse f =
    cataTree (pure EmptyTree)
             (\a ls cs rs -> Node <$> f a <*> ls <*> cs <*> rs)

instance Functor TernaryTree where
  fmap = fmapDefault

instance Foldable TernaryTree where
  foldMap = foldMapDefault
```

Obviously, you're not at a point where you're going to want to do anything so fancy, but such techniques are actually useful once you're in the position of wanting to produce a bunch of functions quickly.